# Can the spot of a laser on a plane be extinguished by another laser?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser, interference

Of course the second laser have to be stabilized with the first in frequency. The second one is fed to the spot through a variable delay line so the phase to be completely opposite.
I suppose they both should extinguish each other provided they are waves and waves interfere destructively in this case and provided the photons do not interfere only with themselves as Dirac tells about the electrons.

Comment: Maybe this demonstration will interest you https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-006-video-demonstrations-in-lasers-and-optics-spring-2008/demonstrations-in-physical-optics/destructive-interference-2014-where-does-the-light-go/

Comment: Thank you but I'm interested in two lasers.

Comment: I hope you watched the video, as it made me understand that a laser beam system is a quantum mechanical whole, and the energy distributed in interference can equally go back to the laser source with total destructive interference.

Comment: "The second one is fed to the spot through a variable delay line so the phase to be completely opposite." I think it is experimentally  impossible to get the phases right in your thought experiment ( that is why in the video the same laser is used, so to know that the phases are possible.

Comment: Why should it be impossible? It is the same as for a single beam which is split in two and the one arm is made a bit longer by n.lambda/2? The frequency is more of concern I think but now there are methods for lock-in which will provide stable and equal frequency.

Comment: NO absolutely not.  See my answer below.

Comment: Just to be clear absolutely not. Light does not work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the spot of a laser on a plane be extinguished by another laser?

To control the phases between two equal frequency lasers is not easy.

> The second one is fed to the spot through a variable delay line so the phase to be completely opposite

In in this video experiment [Destructive Interference — Where does the Light go?](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-006-video-demonstrations-in-lasers-and-optics-spring-2008/demonstrations-in-physical-optics/destructive-interference-2014-where-does-the-light-go/)  two beams are created from the same laser and the phase differences are controlled by small displacements of the optical path.

It shows that on the screen the interference pattern of the two beams can become completely zero, and shows that the energy of the beams goes back to the source. The whole is one quantum mechanical system.

So if you can manage to have  180 degree out of phase two independent  same frequency laser beams hitting the screen, the result should be the same, they would interfere destructively the energy going back to the different  sources.

you say

> provided the photons do not interfere only with themselves

Photons are elementary particles and no elementary particle interferes with itself in today's mainstream physics. It has a complex wavefunction describing its quantum mechanical state, $Ψ$  and $Ψ^*Ψ$ is the **probability** of finding the particle at (x,y,z,t).

Comment: In the video there is a clear way how the photons go back to the source. BS act like mirrors. In the case of two separate sources (lasers) shining on a spot I can not see waht will make photons to return,

Comment: I recall an experiment by Mandelstam where it was observed interference by two lasers but the moral was it was possible only if it was impossible to tell which photon from what laser came. So in this sense I mean that each photon only interfered with it own wavefuntion.

Comment: @Mercury  the "single wavefunction" of the laser+photon system gives zero probability for the photon to  be found on the screen.

Comment: So you think two lasers can extinguish themselves by proper conditions. Some one has to have made such experiment.

Comment: There is no such extinguishment.

Answer (score 0):

Lasers create a speckle pattern when they shine on a rough surface, the old fashioned description is called "interference" but we know today that 2 photons never interfere and cancel .... that would be a violation of conservation of energy!  Dirac and as well Feynman and many other scientists  know that each photon (or electron) determines its own probable path.  Dirac said a "photon interferes with itself" but the modern interpretation is that each photon takes its own path, Feynman used the path integral to explain this.

If you shine 2 lasers you will just get 2 speckle patterns, doubling the brightness.

It is important to know that an excited electron in an atom can stay in this state for a period of time .... many virtual photons/forces are emitted by this electron.   At some time the electron will release its energy to the EM field, it will only do this if somewhere in the universe there is another atom/electron that will absorb the energy ... the EM field is very dynamic.

All light is absorbed by matter... just like waves crashing on a beach ... the medium never absorbs/cancels the energy.